# ANTLR Grammar - Parsing labels and instructions

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar

I'm writting an interpreter which uses an Instruction List code. I'm having some problems when I try to write the grammar for instructions with labels.

I'd like to parser this code block:

```
LD 4
ST A
LD A
EQ 4
ST _AUX_1
(* IF *)
LDN _AUX_1
JMPC _label_2 
(* THEN *)
LD B
EQ 3
ST _AUX_2
_label_2: (* ELSE *)
_label_1: (* END IF*)
LD TRUE
```

As you can see those labels are in a single line without instructions, but the language I'have to parser allows "label + instruction" in a line. So, there are three differents kinds of combinations of instruction and label:

1. Instruction
2. Label:
3. Label: Instruction

I can parse 1 and 2, but I'm not able to parse all of the different combinations.

This is an extract of my ANTLR grammar:

```
program_il : instruction* ;

instruction 
        : ID':' // label
        | ID_INST operand
        ;

operando
    : ID
    | CTE_INT
    | CTE_BOOL
    ;
```

I tried to change the grammar to:

```
instruction : (ID':')? instruction? ;
```

But I've got next error:

```
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
[14:43:49] error(201): Analizador.g:131:29: The following alternatives can never be matched: 2
```

Could someone help me with this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you now accept `Label: Instruction`, the grammar is ambiguous. The parser cannot make a distinction between:

```
lbl:
LD 4
```

and

```
lbl: LD 4
```

In other words, you need to let your `instruction`s be separated by some sort of delimiter. A line break would do the trick as the following demo demonstrates:

```
grammar T;

program_il
 : NL* instruction (NL+ instruction)* NL* EOF
 ;

instruction 
 : ID ':' (ID_INST operand)?
 | ID_INST operand
 ;

operand
 : ID
 | CTE_INT
 | CTE_BOOL
 ;

CTE_BOOL
 : 'TRUE'
 | 'FALSE'
 ;

ID_INST
 : 'LD'
 | 'ST'
 | 'EQ'
 | 'LDN'
 | 'JMPC'
 ;

ID
 : ('_' | 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ('_' | 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9')*
 ;

CTE_INT
 : ('0'..'9')+
 ;

NL
 : '\r'? '\n'
 | '\r'
 ;

COMMENT
 : '(*' .* '*)' {skip();}
 ;

SPACE
 : (' ' | '\t')+ {skip();}
 ;
```

Now parsing the input:

```
(* IF *)
JMPC _label_2 
(* THEN *)
LD B
ST _AUX_2
_label_2: LDN _AUX_1 (* ELSE *)
_label_1: (* END IF*)
LD TRUE
```

will result in the following tree:

[image]

Comment: +1 but, though I'm not familiar with ANTLR, I think it would have been cleaner to  do "instruction : (ID ':')? ID_INST operand;".

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, alas, that does not work with ANTLR :). With  LL parsers, it's often a good idea to *not* have optional rules at the left most side.

Comment: Oh, I know - it must be LL(1) :)

Comment: Thank you.You're right, the NL delimiter makes everything works fine ;)